# How to use “and” with “seq-reduce” in Elisp?

Tags: elisp, special-form

I’m trying to write something like this:

```
(setq l '(nil t nil nil))
(seq-reduce 'and l t)
```

I get this error:

> Invalid function: and

My understanding, after a bit of googling, is that this is due to `and` being a `special form`.
What would be a good way to make this work? Is there a function equivalent to `and`? Is there some way to make a function out of a special form? I couldn’t find any documentation about this. I tried to write a function that does what `and` does, but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `seq-reduce` function uses `funcall` to invoke its function argument, and [as shown in the `funcall` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html), a special form like `and` can't be passed to it; calling `(funcall 'and t nil)` results in an `Invalid function: #<subr and>` error.

You can make the call to `and` in a `lambda` instead:

```lisp
(let ((l '(nil t nil nil)))
  (seq-reduce (lambda (acc v) (and acc v)) l t))
```

Comment: But`(lambda (acc v) (and acc v))` only takes two arguments. How can I generalize this for any number of arguments, as with `and`?

Comment: It doesn't need to be generalized because in the context of `seq-reduce`, the function is called with only two arguments: the first argument is either the initial value (for the first call) or the accumulated value (for all subsequent calls), and the second argument is the next element of the sequence. Even if you could pass `and` directly, `seq-reduce` would only ever call it with two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function equivalent to `and`?

There is not and *cannot* be a function equivalent to `and`, because functions evaluate all of their arguments before they are called, and that is in conflict with the behaviour of `and` which *must* only evaluate as many arguments as necessary to produce its result.

Imagine `(and ok-to-delete (delete-it-all))` if `and` was a function, for instance.  In Lisp it's necessary that the likes of `and` and `or` do not unnecessarily evaluate all of their arguments, and therefore they cannot be functions.

Comment: n.b. I adapted this answer from the comments I'd made on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78258, which is a broadly similar question that ended up being closed for being unfocused, but which nevertheless might be useful reading.